# Asus Laptop Part Compatability - SSD and RAM Upgrades

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, ssd, compatibility

I have an Asus GL702VS Laptop that I got from a relative a weeks ago. It came with a 128GB SSD + 1TB HDD (SATA), and 12GB of DDR4. I am considering upgrading this laptop to more "capable specs" for gaming on a budget.

I want to upgrade the RAM to 16GB DDR4, as the original configuration of the RAM is 8GB+4GB, so it would make sense to upgrade the 4GB to 8GB.

Here is [the RAM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XC4W1LQ) I am thinking of purchasing.

The HDD is 1TB in size, which is respectable, but is not as fast as I would like it to be. I want to upgrade the HDD to an SSD, a Samsung SSD to be exact.

Here is [the SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OBRFFAS) I am considering.

What I want to know is, are these two parts compatible with my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say no and yes.

> https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-GL702VS/specifications/

According to the specs I found at the above link, the memory is a no-go.  The stick you chose is 2666Mhz and the motherboard only takes 2400Mhz.  It doesn't even list other speed options in the specs, so you'll need to use the 2400Mhz version of that same dimm.  There's the 2400Mhz option link on the page you posted or check out the link @DrZoo posted, if you can't find it on your page.

DrZoo made me look at the spec sheet a little closer and made me realize it's probably a "purchase options" sheet, rather than  "compatibility" sheet.  Just because it lists a handful of drive options, doesn't mean that it it will *only* use those drives (like I previously thought), so the 1TB SSD should work.

DrZoo also mentions that the current drives are 2.5", so the one you are looking at should fit physically, without an adapter.

Comment: What makes you think the laptop can't have a 1 TB SSD? The specs listed simply state that those are the drive options you can choose from when buying the laptop. It doesn't mean it's limited to those sizes.

Comment: I interpreted it to be a "compatibility" sheet, rather than a "purchase options" sheet.  I guess it's probably the latter, now that I think about it.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I was just curious if I was really missing something or where you found that. To clear it up for the question asker, a 1 TB SSD would work.

Comment: You can edit your answer and correct the info. You are correct about the RAM being incompatible. Here is the link for [compatible 2400 MHz SO-DIMMs](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01DGOF7EA/?tag=stackoverflow17-20&th=1). A 2.5" drive will also work, because the drives that are in it right now are 2.5" drives.